# Windows Identity Foundation and Port Forwarding on port 3349

Tags: mysql

1. cant seem to get our port 9443 to listen can seem to get our port
   9443
2. We added more disk space
3. Do we need to rebuild database

Comment: @Hector.Lopez - is it 3349 or 9443 ??  And what is your actual question?

Comment: What is the problem?